# C++ code does not compile

Tags: c++

The code does not compile. I do not understand what the error is, help please)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class Record{
    std::string product_name;
    std::string product_category;
    int price;
    int amount;
public:
Record(std::string newName, std::string newCategory, int newPrice, int newAmount){
    product_name=newName;
    product_category=newCategory;
    price=newPrice;
    amount=newAmount;
}

    std::string getName(){
        return product_name;
    }
    std::string getCategory(){
        return product_category;
    }
    int getPrice(){
        return price;
    }
    int getAmount(){
        return amount;
    }
    void setName(std::string newName){
        product_name=newName;
    }
    void setCategory(std::string newCategory){
        product_category=newCategory;
    }
    void setPrice(int newPrice){
        price=newPrice;
    }
    void setAmount(int newAmount){
        amount=newAmount;
    }
};

int main(){
    Record r1;
    r1.setName("beer");
    r1.setCategory("alcohol");
    r1.setPrice(12);
    r1.setAmount(32);
    Record r2("carrot", "vegetables", 123, 1932);
    std::cout<<r1.getName()<<" "<<r1.getCategory()<<" "<<r1.getPrice()<<" "<<r1.getAmount()<< std::endl;
    std::cout<<r2.getName()<<" "<<r2.getCategory()<<" "<<r2.getPrice()<<" "<<r2.getAmount()<< std::endl;
    Record r3[2];
    std::string a;
    float b;
    unsigned int c;
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<2; ++i){
        std::cout<<"input name: ";
        std::cin>>a;
        r3[i].setName(a);
        std::cout<<"input category: ";
        std::cin>>a;
        r3[i].setCategory(a);
        std::cout<<"input price: ";
        std::cin>>b;
        r3[i].setPrice(b);
        std::cout<<"input amount: ";
        std::cin>>c;
        r3[i].setAmount(c);
    }
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<2; ++i){
        std::cout<<r3[i].getName()<<" "<<r3[i].getCategory()<<" "<<r3[i].getPrice()<<" "<<r3[i].getAmount()<< std::endl;

    }

    return 0;

}
```

> Error text:
>       g++ -Wall -c "main.cpp" ( /media/ad/4GB-NTFS/prog/laba2)
>       main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>       main.cpp:46:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘Record::Record()’
>            Record r1;
>                   ^
>       main.cpp:12:1: note: candidate: Record::Record(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, int, int)
>        Record(std::string newName, std::string newCategory, int newPrice, int newAmount){
>        ^
>       main.cpp:12:1: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 0 provided
>       main.cpp:6:7: note: candidate: Record::Record(const Record&)
>        class Record{
>              ^
>       main.cpp:6:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
>       main.cpp:54:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘Record::Record()’
>            Record r3[2];
>                       ^
>       main.cpp:12:1: note: candidate: Record::Record(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, int, int)
>        Record(std::string newName, std::string newCategory, int newPrice, int newAmount){
>        ^
>       main.cpp:12:1: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 0 provided
>       main.cpp:6:7: note: candidate: Record::Record(const Record&)
>        class Record{
>              ^
>       main.cpp:6:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

Comment: Note the words immediately following "error": `no matching function for call to ‘Record::Record()‘`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overriden the constructor of your class, and so there is not one that accepts zero arguments as this requires:

```
Record r1;
```

Define a default constructor:

```
Record() {}
```

Comment: What defined state does that constructor place the constructed object in?

Comment: I believe each data member of the Record object will be allocated and the default constructor of each data member called.

Answer (score 2):

Your class doesn't have a default constructor. So when you say:

```
   Record r1;
```

the compiler doesn't know how to create the `r1` object. You either need to provide all the parameters when `r` is created:

```
  Record r1( "foo", "bar", 1, 2 );
```

or better completely rethink the design of your program.

Answer (score 0):

> main.cpp:46:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘Record::Record()’

That is, at this point:

```
Record r1;
```

You are trying to instantiate the object `r1` with a default constructor (`Record::Record`). Indeed you are not providing any parameter.

Moreover the compiler continues:

> note: candidate expects 4 arguments, 0 provided

Following your *class interface*, the only way to instantiate a `Record` object is to use the only constructor provided, that is:

```
Record(std::string, std::string, int, int);
```

If you want to allow to instantiate an `Record` object with a default constructor you have to provide it.

C++11 allows you to write:

```
Record() = default;
```

In order to define a default constructor.

Comment: A default constructor rarely makes sense - in this case it's hard to see how a default constructed object would be useful.

Comment: @NeilButterworth if default constructor didn't make sense, the modern standard would not have defined a new keyword in order to explicitly generate it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a constructor with no parameters.

`Record r1` tries to call `Record()` but it doesn't find it. Just add the extra constructor in your class. It can be empty. This will also solve the same problem with `Record r3[2]`.

P.S. (unrelated to the question, but helpful)

Looking at your code, I suggest you check out [member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) for implementing your constructors. Why? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list).